# Getting granular data in template from an entity referenced in the entity_reference field, in a way that would respect Drupal's caching

Tags: 8, entities

I have a case where in my node's template I need an image style URL from the Media entity referenced by this node. I need a raw value of this URL to use it like that: `<div style="background-image: url('[my-image-url-goes-here]')">`

I know multiple ways of achieving this, like using `twig_tweak` module (but I think it would be an overkill) or preprocessing hook (feels ugly), or creating custom `twig` filters for extracting data that I need. Actually I could even do something like that: `content.field_media_image|render|striptags|spaceless` to isolate URL returned by rendered `Media` display but that is especially ridiculous and would work with only single value. After few hours of research I started considering creating a custom formatter for `entity_reference` fields, that would just output raw data, like for example:

```
[
  '#url' => $my_image_style_url,
]
```

That looks nice, I could then just set it as a formatter of my `entity_reference` field referencing my `Media` image entity and I could use this `#url` in my node as I wish. But it seems to have one weakness. I cannot set cache tags on that, because it's not renderable - it would be rendered in parent template that may not have cache tags that would ensure that it would be cleared if one of values sent to it that way, would change for reasons unrelated to this node. So it doesn't feel like a right solution in the end.

Now I'm starting to realize that I cannot reliably do what I wanted, because by isolating one information from a field like that, I'm automatically ignoring its cache tags. Is making ugly preprocessing hooks the only option I have for that? Am I missing something?

Comment: Whether it feels ugly or not, a preprocessor is how to do this. You'll set up a variable containing the image style URL, and use that in your template. This will respect caching systems.

Comment: The field formatter interface requires view() to return a render array, which then, when rendered, will bubble cache data. All hacks you find on the internet hacking `{{ content }}` are bad examples like the one in your question. The solution of your problem is adding a template (which might be an inline template if you don't want to make the extra effort to provide one in the module) and adjusting the CSS rather than trying to produce a verbatim HTML output.

Comment: Actually I think I found a solution. In my formatter I can return my values AND return cache tags, and then just render these cache tags in template I'm using my values in, like so `{{  {'#cache': content.field_myfield.0['#cache']} }}`. That way cache tags will be actually bubbled and I can freely use any values returned from my formatter. It isn't prettiest solution but is vastly cleaner than using preprocessing if I have configurable output - like with image styles - this configuration can be stored in formatters and changed per field easily. I think that may be actually the cleanest way.

Comment: But you still need to get a value from inside of the fields render array, which is not a good idea, because the position of the value can change at any time, for example by using a layout module. Why not render the inline CSS in the field directly and target the div container with CSS selectors?

Comment: What you can do from the field is to bubble up an attachment along with the cache metadata to add the CSS to <head> , see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/212395/47547

Comment: I agree that reaching inside the `$content` depends on renderable array structure not changing and is not ideal, bit the thing is - it's simple, and doesn't require logic for a single template to be in multiple places, like going through page attachment hook, then through head CSS, just to go back to field through rendered HTML structure to modify it. It's like extremely overcomplicated path to take, which will result in difficult to read code.

Comment: I would be more willing to consider just creating a custom extra field that would be rendering custom template pulling all data needed there from related entities. That would be at least direct.

Comment: No, you don't need the page attachment hook, you can add it in #attached like #cache data and then it will bubble up when {{ content }} is rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105339/discussion-between-lukasz-zaroda-and-4k4).